# Customizable tiles inside app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, tiles

I want to display items as tiles inside my app. The HubTile control is to inflexible for me, so I use this [solution with a listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372733/how-can-i-make-something-like-this-tiles-inside-the-app-windows-phone). I have a few types of items and they should be displayed differently. For example, the note item has a title and a text while the image item has a image source and a name.

[image: enter note tile] [image: image tile]

Implement two styles for note and image and creating the ListBoxItem dynamically with each style seems to me as an easy way, but is it the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an ItemsControl that has mutliple data types in its ItemsSource and each data type has a different DataTemplate, you should use something like DataTemplateSelector.

I've written about this topic in the context of WP7/WP8 @ [ListBox with multiple ItemTemplates in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075542/listbox-with-multiple-itemtemplates-in-windows-phone-8/14077757#14077757)